# How to Implement a Separate Checking/Savings Account with Different Methods

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am trying to create a simple banking system that has clients with both checking and savings account. Both types of accounts inherit from an Account class. The differences in the accounts are that checks can be written from a checking account and interest can be added to a savings account. However, because I am using polymorphism, I have not been able to find a way to access a method to write a check because the method does not exist in the superclass. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code. You're almost certainly misinterpreting something, because subclasses are allowed to have methods that are not found in the superclass.

Comment: I understand that but I cannot access the methods from a driver class because they are not found in the superclass

Answer (score 0):

I would not have "write a check" as a method.

I'd start with an interface that would define what all Accounts can do:

```
public interface Account {
    void deposit(Money amount);
    void withdraw(Money amount);
    Money getBalance();    
}
```

Start with that.  Have `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingAccount` implement that interface (or create an `AbstractAccount` and have both extend it).

Once you have that, ask yourself: What is the polymorphic difference between the two?  My guess is that one is interest bearing and the other is not.  Both might be subject to fees that differ.

There is something beyond `Account` that is needed here.

I'd have a `Bank` class that would manage a collection of `Account`.  It would decide when to pay interest based on some schedule (e.g. on the first of every month if compounded monthly).  The `Bank` could loop over the `Account` collection and deposit the amount calculated from the balance on that day into every `SavingsAccount`.

As you can see, the interface for all accounts holds up nicely.